# Seting reminder for special dates in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my app i want to set some reminders.The user need an option to select the reminder on the day he wishes.(for eg:user need reminder for Monday, not need for Tuesday etc).i have already implemented a local notification and it is working fine,But i have some confusions in implementing the reminder for particular days.Do i have to implement seven reminders for this purpose?
Can anyone give a hand for this issue please.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the `repeatInterval` property, that you can specify only the predefined calendar units.

```
enum {
   NSEraCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitEra,
   NSYearCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitYear,
   NSMonthCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitMonth,
   NSDayCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitDay,
   NSHourCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitHour,
   NSMinuteCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitMinute,
   NSSecondCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitSecond,
   NSWeekCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitWeek,
   NSWeekdayCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitWeekday,
   NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal
   NSQuarterCalendarUnit = kCFCalendarUnitQuarter,
};
```

So, if you want the notification to repeat on any of these above intervals you can use the *repeatInterval* property with any of these values. But if you want the notification to repeat on intervals some like "Every Two Days" or on some irregular intervals, then you have to create individual notifications for each of those reminders.